@$ in search history
Once I type /, if I also type <Up> to look up into the search history, most of the times appears the (annoying) string @$, so that the command line is /@$, which results in a 'Pattern not found' error if <CR> is pressed.
After searching into the doc, it seems to me that @$ is not a register reference.. So what could be the cause of this ?
EDIT:
I can remove that from history search using:
:call histdel("/", "@.*$")

but this is not the ideal solution to prevent this..
EDIT2:
The "problem" is caused by searching into Netrw buffer. If I search while I am in Netrw, and then I hit <CR> to confirm, the @$ is included in search history...

It seems that if Netrw is used (e.g. Lex or Sex) the searches ^$ and @$ are added to the history at least with version 8.1 onward of Vim (but not with version 7.4).

I think I found the problem. Can you check if this commit fixes it for you? https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/a063b22b3bbc1c7ad9d985b14d6e3c5b7c6e3eca

@ChristianBrabandt, yes! It seems it solves the issue! Thank you!

@VivianDeSmedt I use Explore.

@ChristianBrabandt could you tell me what is the NetrwKeepJ token in the code? I don't see where it is defined and I don't understand how to use in other code.

@VivianDeSmedt it seems it is defined as a command in runtime/autoload/netrw.vim line 610 and 613, right ?

@xyx my mistake :-) Thanks!

That seems to be a bug in the netrw plugin, distributed by Vim.
Good thing is, I have commit rights ;) so I was able to fix it with this commit, which uses :keeppatterns to execute commands like :global without modifying search history.

After updating the last tag from GitHub, the problem reappears (I suppose accidentally) for \a.

That must be a different problem however. please create an issue and mention exactly what you did. Potentially also bisect the plugin to find which commit broke it

OK I will structure the issue as best I can. Tracking the issuing tag will be time consuming since I should test every one after the above commit. Thanks in advance.

Also, I forgot to mention that I noticed that when I enter into a directory with Netrw, the selected file/directory is always the last one in the list. I did not change the setup of Netrw in the last few months.

are you sure that \a does not appear in v9.1.0846, which is the tag of the commit ? I still face the \a issue, but strangely, it seems that is conditioned by the number of items listed in Netrw... For example, it happens after searching in$HOME where I have many dirs, but not in others where I have a few (6)..

I found the root cause: issue opened.

As I noted in EDIT2 in my original post, the "problem" is caused by searching into Netrw buffer. If I search while I am in Netrw, and then it '' to confirm, the @$ is included in search history...
The solution I came up at the moment is to use the following autocmd:
autocmd BufLeave,BufDelete,BufHidden,BufWipeout * if (&ft == "netrw") | silent! :call histdel("/", "@.*$") | silent! :call histdel("/", "\a") endif

which seems to work quiet fine...
Of course I am open to more elegant solutions!

You should open an issue so that the plugin's author can look into it.

In fact the solution is not totally correct because if I search @.*$ in a buffer, it will be incorrectly removed from the history.

delhist('/', '\^\$') and delhist('/', '@\$') make the job and delete only the entries you want.

Thanks! Useful to know. Another vim tip to the list.
